# JS // Lines after try statement execute before the try statement has finished

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
notConnected = true;

while (notConnected == true) {
    notConnected = false;

    try {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9042/");

        ws.onopen = function () {
            console.log("connected");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        notConnected = true;
        console.error(error);
    }
    sleep(1000);
    console.log(notConnected)
}
```

Here is the output:

```
false                                                             liveview.js:40

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9042/' failed:            liveview.js:16
```

I would expect these results to be the other way round. To me, it seems like the rest of the while block is running while the WebSocket is still trying to connect, and eventually failing (which is fine - it should keep trying to connect until it is successful), hence the state of notConnected being logged before the error is.

If I am correct, is there a way to stop the code until the try statement is finished?

Comment: When doing `ws.onopen` will attach an event to the ws, and will complete executing the code normally, and once `ws` actually opens the function attached to `ws.onopen` will be executed.

Comment: Opening a websocket is asynchronous, so your code doesn't wait for it to complete or fail before doing `console.log(notConnected)`

Comment: What's the point of the `while` loop if you are going to set the break condition immediately? All this does is make the loop body run once, which you will get without the loop.